# Test class for Apex Trigger for update

Tags: salesforce, apex, test-class, apex-trigger

I am new in Apex Development. I want to write a TestClass for my Apex Trigger.

I am sharing my code with you:

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity o:Trigger.New) {
        if(o.Probability==100 && o.Invoiced__c == true)
        {            
            Attachment a = new Attachment();
            try {
                a = [Select Id, Name from Attachment where ParentId =:o.Id];
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                a = null;
            }
            if (a == null)
                o.addError('Add an attachment before you close the Opportunity');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodluck

```
public static void testmethod(){

opportunity opp = new opportunity()
//change whatever fields u need to make probability 100%
opp.stage = 'Closed Won';
opp.Invoiced__c == true;

try{

insert opp
}
catch(Exception e){

string errormessage = e.getMessage();

}
//now that u know how to do it, do a positive test where you also add an          
//attachment
//as a side note, your catch block will never fire, because you aren't     
//catching any exceptions you are just getting a null string
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim,         I got the Error "Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'void'. at line 2 column 15 "

Comment: Thank u so much i did some changes and it was working fine

Comment: it was more of pseudocode with the logic behind it, I hope you also saw my notes at the end saying your catch block in your trigger is flawed

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things that need to be done :-
1. Create a record in 'Opportunity' object. Update it using code.
2. Create an attachment. Here is the link for your reference https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yzKIAQ

Comment: Trigger is working fine but ii don't know how write the code for above trigger.